# Jbpm : ended TaskInstance transitions

Tags: task, transition, jbpm

I don't understand something in JBPM API. I have two users on a task at the same time. The first one chooses a transition and completes the task, so the TaskInstance is now ended. The second user does the same but gets a nullPointerException : getAvalaibleTransition() returns null.

Why would getAvailableTransition() (of class TaskInstance) return null ? It's the same node, transitions should be the same ?

I am a total newbie with JBPM. Just testing the behaviour of an application in response to competitive actions and ran into this error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are using jBPM 3.x right?
If you have one single instance of a business process, why do you have two users in one task? You are probably missing the idea of Process Instance, so can you describe your business situation? Because if one user complete a task, then that task can not be worked by another user. 
Cheers

Comment: Actually there is an instance of process. And one task in the process which needs to complete a form. Several users can access the task at the same time (there is no lock at the moment, don't ask me why... I tried to convince my hierarchy but they don't want a lock). Hence, two users can complete the form at the same time. But the second user gets the error I described when he validates because there are no transitions available...

Comment: What I have done to solve this at the moment is testing that the task isn't over before getting the transitions... and when the second user tries to end the task, he gets the error "task already ended" instead of "nullPointerException".

Yes it is JBPM 3.x